# Infinite goroutines until received desired response

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm trying launch goroutines in an infinite loop until I get the response I'm looking for but the `select` is unreachable if I change `for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {}` to `for {}`. What's a pattern for solving this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func myFunc() float64 {

    c := make(chan float64)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {

            var value float64
            value = someOp()

            if value > .9 {
                c <- value
            }

        }()
    }

    // unreachable code the if the for loop above is infinite
    for {
        select {
        case x := <-c:
            return x
        default:
        }
    }

}

func someOp() float64 {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    return rand.Float64()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(myFunc())
}
```

Comment: Starting an unlimited number of goroutines is usually not a good idea.  A better approach is to start a fixed number of goroutines that search for a solution.

Comment: I don’t actually want an infinite number of goroutines but rather to continue adding racers until one of them wins and then discard all the losers.

Comment: if the 1st for loop is infinite, then the program control will not come out of it at all and you will be generating infinite number of go routines .

Comment: Perhaps I should simply try N racers and if there are still no winners at the end of the race then have another race (start another loop). Basically I am trying to refactor a recursive function with go routines and channels.

Comment: use quit for sending value on a channel to quit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting an unlimited number of goroutines is usually not a good idea. A better approach is to start a fixed number of goroutines that loop looking for an answer. Return from these goroutines when an answer is found.

```
func myFunc() float64 {
    c := make(chan float64, 1) // Size 1 prevents race between main goroutine and workers

    done := make(chan struct{})
    defer close(done)

    // Start a fixed number of goroutines
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                select {
                case <-done:
                    // myfunc exited with result, return from this goroutine
                    return
                default:
                    var value float64
                    value = someOp()
                    if value > .9 {
                        select {
                        case c <- value:
                            // This is first goroutine to send a value
                        default:
                            // Another goroutine sent a value
                        }
                        return
                    }

                }
            }
        }()
    }
    return <-c
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/SRpeT8k34eA

Comment: Unfortunately like the code posted in my question this doesn't solve the recursion problem.

Comment: @malablaster I answered the question as posed. Update the question to explain your requirements including an example that reflects those requirements. Nothing in the question indicates that recursion is required.

Comment: Recursion is mentioned in the comments. I’m not seeing what value your solution adds over my original code. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @malablaster the value added is that this solution actually works... you'll have to elaborate on what difference it makes that your function is recursive. I can't see how that would change anything.

Comment: @malablaster The comment says that you are refactoring a recursive function. That does not imply that recursion is required, nor does it provide enough information to answer your question.  For example, I don't know if the recursion is in `myFunc` or `someOp`.

Comment: The code in the question calls `someOp` ten times and leaks goroutines if more than one call to `someOp`  returns a value > .9.  The code in this answer calls `someOp` until a result is found and does not leak goroutines.

Comment: @ThunderCat I'm not clear on what you mean by leaks goroutines since I believe they'll be abandoned and GC'd.

Recursion does matter: what happens in your solution if 10 iterations occur without a solution?

I had assumed the recursion in `myFunc` was evident because of the talk of an infinite loop but I think I was wrong it wasn't clear.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear The original code works too. See above comment for the significance of recursion.

Comment: @malablaster you mention recursion, but the significance in unclear. In response to your question to ThunderCat, it doesn't run 10 iterations, it runs 10 gouroutines which run infinitely until one spits out a value, then they all quit. Notice the inner for loop is an infinite one, but will return when finished. See this example I made it harder and printed. https://play.golang.org/p/DfbUkkZT4TD

Comment: @RayfenWindspear I see. My mistake I didn't get that before; my eye glossed over the `for` loop in there. Ok now I get the value. Yes that is a good approach. Run 10 things infinitely rather than (trying to add) infinite things that run once.

Comment: Thanks @rayfenwindspear and thundercat for your help. I’m new to concurrency thinking but regardless I now realize how silly what i was trying to do was.

Comment: @malablaster See https://play.golang.org/p/t3YbfS_QQ9a for demonstration of leak.  First goroutine to send on channel is successful and returns.  Subsequent goroutines to send on channel block and leak.

Comment: @ThunderCat Isn't it the same problem in your solution though? It seems to me like all 10 goroutines still run in spite of the first one getting the answer: https://play.golang.org/p/euwolBx6rCh

Comment: The playground  link in previous comment does not show if goroutines exit or not. The answer uses select w/ default to avoid leak present in the question.   https://play.golang.org/p/VNJmM2BM29Y